# Check the a matrix column values, if 0 occurs more than 10 time, than delete the column in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a large matrix, if column values contain more than 10 zeros ('0') , delete the whole column in matlab.

Comment: Do you also have a question?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can do it using the [`sum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) function and logical operations (see [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)).

```
% Create matrix.
% First, Second and Fourth columns have 20 ones each.
M = ones(20, 4);

% Third column has 20 zeros.
M(:, 3) = 0;

% Delete columns that have more than 10 zeros.
M(:, sum(M == 0, 1) > 10) = [];
```

Comment: You need to specify a second argument to sum

Comment: @MadPhysicist Please read the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html). `If A is a matrix, then sum(A) returns a row vector containing the sum of each column`

Comment: That is probably about as good as you are going to get.

Comment: @Cebri ah, but before the clause about `A` being a matrix, there's the clause about `A` being a vector (`sum` works along the first non-singleton dimension, as do most reduction functions in MATLAB). So, if `M` happened to have only a single row, your code wouldn't work quite as you intend (although as it happens, you'd probably get away with it since the result I think would be guaranteed empty). I would add the dimension argument to `sum` to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Edric Thanks a lot for the feedback. I understand the implications. I have updated the code with [`dim`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#inputarg_dim)`= 1` for more robustness.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MathWorks discussion](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/37323-count-the-number-of-non-zero-elements-of-a-column-row-of-a-2d-matrix?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), the accepted way of finding the count of zero elements by column is something like

```
sum(A == 0, 1);
```

You can use logical indexing to delete all the columns where this is greater than 10:

```
A = A(:, sum(A == 0, 1) >= 10);
```

Comment: I think that you want the second input to be `1` so that it counts the number of zeros in a column rather than a row.

Comment: I want to delete that column which have more than 10 zeros values, others columns have different values like 1,2,3 & so on...

Comment: @Suever. You are right of course. Fixed.

Comment: @SaghirAhmed. My mistake. Fixed to operate on columns instead of rows.